# Checkbox not visible in restrictions by carriers in Prestashop 1.7 payment preferences

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have version 1.7.8.11 and I cannot select carriers in the payment preferences, they appear with a double dash instead of the checkbox.

[image]

I have uninstalled the carriers several times and reinstalled them but there is no way. I also don't see the difference between 31, which has the visible checkboxes, and the others. What is the reason why the checkboxes do not appear?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug once.

Check your DB , you probably have some problem in the **ps_carrier** table in relation to the link between **id_carrier** and **id_reference** for active carriers.

This causes a problem in Symfony's form generation for the affected carrier(s).